# Split an Array and get the Index

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I've an Array like this,

```
[
  1,
  1,
  1,
  0,
  0,
  0,
  1,
  1,
  0,
  1,
  1
]
```

In above array I need to get split on `0` and `1`  numbers and also their `index`. I write the code for getting `0` and `1` in separate array but I want their index also in the Main array, below code is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [Array count]; i++) {
       NSString* strV = [Array objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"ArrayCount:%@",strV);
         if ([strV isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]) {
                [getArray addObject:strV];
                   }
    }

    NSLog(@"getArray:%@",getArray.description);
}
```

Then, how can I get index of `0`, can you please help me. Thank you

Comment: Arrays don't have indexPaths.  If you want the index, you already have it; it's the loop counter (`i`).

Comment: Do you want a separate array for index or same array should contain index of 0 as well?

Comment: same array should contain 0 and 1

Comment: first i need separate both 0 and 1 after i want index position of 0 and 1 in the main array

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. What does "get split on `0` and `1'" numbers mean? What output do yo want? You want to put all the `1` numbers in one output array, and all the `0` numbers in a second output array? And then you say you want their indexes. So you want 2 new arrays that contain some other object (a dictionary?) That holds both a `1` or a `0` number, as well as it's index in the original array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 NSArray *mainArr=@[@1,@1,@1,@0,@0,@0,@1,@1,@0,@1,@1];
    NSMutableArray *tempArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i=0;i<[mainArr count];i++){
        if([[mainArr objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]){
            NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:tempArr];
            [tempArr removeAllObjects];
            NSDictionary *dic=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0],@"value",[NSNumber numberWithInt:i],@"index",nil];
            [tempArr addObject:dic];
            [tempArr addObjectsFromArray:arr];
        }else if ([[mainArr objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]){
            NSDictionary *dic=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],@"value",[NSNumber numberWithInt:i],@"index",nil];
            [tempArr addObject:dic];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",tempArr.description);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *arrayContainZero = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *arrayWithZeroIndexes = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSNumber *numberZero in Array)
{
    if(numberZero.integerValue == 0)
    {
            [arrayContainZero addObject:numberZero];
            [arrayWithZeroIndexes      addObject:@([arrayContainZeroindexOfObject:numberZero])];

    }
}
```